# Cannot find bean to autowire which is in maven dependencies in jar,

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I add jar with bean using maven.
Than I want to autowire them in context file...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="statisticsService" class="com.ac.kpi.AcStatisticsService">
        <constructor-arg name="dataService" ref="acDataService"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Problem: when I run tomcat I get Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ac.kpi.StatisticsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
```

Despite the fact that all maven dependencies are imported and present.
MoreOver in Idea, in LinuxOS everyring work, problem is only in eclipse, Windows OS.

Comment: Check your war/ear file where the spring jars are included in it. check the scope of the jar in pom file.

Comment: looks everithing ok, moreover, another beans are loaded properly.

Comment: Did you add annotation driven tag in the root context xml?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of exception is thrown if Spring doesn't find any bean to autowire. This may be due to the fact that you are autowiring an interface but there is no actual implementation of that interface. Check if this is the case of your StatisticsService.

Comment: yes it is interface, can you tell me why it is impossible to use interface for autowire?

Comment: I wrote an actual answer because I don't have enough reputation to write a comment... I'm going to rephrase my answer sorry. @Edgar you can autowire an interface but you will also need the implementation of that interface or Spring won't find it and so it will throw this Exception.

Comment: implementation is present in the same jar.

Comment: Ok then the problem may be the constructor argument. Have you registered that bean somewhere else? If not, just add the following line to your beans.xml:
<bean id="acDataService" class="the_data_Service_class"/>

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with you sometimes. Delete the local com.ac.* package file in .m2, then download it again.